# Best practice to include categorical features along with sequences in LSTM for sequence prediction?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a dataset with sequences and categorical attributes associated with each sequence.

What is the best practice to include these categorical attributes in order to capture sequence variations across different attributes?

An example df

```
 Sequence      |   Country   |   User  |
[A,B,D,E,F]          USA          U1
[B,C,D,E]            DE           U123
[A,B,F,E,G,H]        USA          U2456
  ...                ...          ....
```

I want to build an LSTM model which will be able to predict the next event in the sequence.

I know how to build the LSTM model if I am only giving it the sequences as input.

But how would I be able to add the attributes Country and User as well?

If I apply one hot encoding on the sequence data, should I concatenate the one hot encoded feature vectors to it?

Or are there any other best practices here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  [functional model API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) and concatenate the categorical feature

for example, you have the country as cateogrical feature, you can [concatenate](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/) it with lstm features as `Concatenate()([lstm, country])`

```
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keraslayers import Input,Concatenate,Dense,Activation

sequence= Input(shape=(seq_length,), name='sequence')
lstm = LSTM(300, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3)(sequence)
country   = Input(shape=(1,))
conc = Concatenate()([lstm, country])
dense_layer = Dense(1)(conc)
x_out= Activation('sigmoid')(dense_layer )
model = Model([sequence, country], x_out)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics['accuracy'])
```

To fit the model, assuming you have reshaped and have prepared sequence column in `sequence` and other feature(country) in `country`

```
 model.fit([sequence,country], y_train)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this code snippet, how would I go about calling the fit function here to provide two different inputs?

Comment: Thanks, the Concatenate() line seems to not work, however, if I instead use the "concatenate" function, it seems to work. from keras.layers import concatenate, conc = concatenate([lstm,country]). Similar to the example in the link you provided.

Comment: can you try this `Concatenate()([lstm, country])` and let me know if this works? I have also included the imports

Comment: Do you know any papers with regards to different tested architectures for event prediction?

Comment: I am my self working with event prediction, havent find anything very promising for it, using LSTMs for now too.

Comment: Thanks for the info, same here. Any links with regards to rule of thumb for dropout and recurrent dropout?

Comment: For me dropouts bout normal and recurrent didnt work much. I saw that validation accuracy improved despite validation error going up (untill certain point), so let it go up for a while and see if that the case for you too. I mean let your early stopping patience value be bit large. (try 0.05-0.3 for both BTW)